# Remove dim duration of AlertDialog

Tags: java, android-alertdialog

The `AlertDialog`'s dim effect can be disabled with:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Also, the dim amount can be changed by using:

```
 alertDialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.0f);
```

However, whenever I call these functions, the change seems to be animated for a short duration (a long value between 100-200). Is there a way to make the change instant?

When trying to replace the standard dim with a mimicking View, the screen seems to flash due to the animation of the dim change.

**Edit:** Here's the base application theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The AlertDialog was created from an AlertDialog.Builder (click listeners have been added later):

```
    dialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Title").setIcon(null).setMessage("Description")
            .setNeutralButton("Neutral",null).setNegativeButton("Cancel",null).setPositiveButton("Ok",null);
    alertDialog=dialogBuilder.create();
```

Comment: please post the alert dialog theme or the app theme or both

Comment: @LenaBru Hello, I have added app theme and the code for creating the AlertDialog, but I'm not sure how to get the alert dialog theme. The AlertDialog was created dynamically and not with xml.

Comment: this = use theme of the context this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answers here suggest, I figured that it's better to just disable the dim effect altogether. I didn't want to override all the AlertDialogs, so it seems to work well enough with just using a background `View` and fading it in/out with the `AlertDialog`'s `setOnShowListener` and `setOnDismissListener`.

```
alertDialog=dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){
    @Override public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        background.setAlpha(0f);background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);background.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(dur);
    }
});

alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener(){
    @Override public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog){
          background.animate().alpha(0f).withEndAction(runnable_background_gone);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your theme:

```
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

And control the theme strictly from code

If you don't want to control the theme of the dialog by the main theme 
create a subclass for the dialog only and use it the following way

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>


dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I try to add the subclass style as you mentioned, but when I open it (`alertDialog.show()`), for some reason it covers the whole application screen.

Comment: see updated answer
try inheriting from Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge instead of your app theme

Comment: Still the same issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the dialogs to have disabled dim then you can do something like this:
Go to styles.xml, then in your main theme add:

```
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/MyAlertDialogTheme</item>
```

Then in below that add another theme (the one we are referencing above)

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Also, if you want a very low dim you can change it to:

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.05</item>
```

Comment: Hello Ofek, when I add `<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/MyAlertDialogTheme</item>` to the app theme, the dialog size is normal but everything behind becomes black when I do `alertDialog.show()`.